# List unique positions from list combined with associated string

Tags: regex, perl

I need to list the unique numerical positions from a file, and then enumerate the unique indels after each position.

If there are multiple different indels then I want each position/indel to be listed on separate lines.

I gather that [`List::MoreUtils:uniq`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) is the best solution but I'm not having any luck. Is there a module-free method?

Please let me know if my explanation doesn't make sense.

FILE1 data:

```
7065_8#10 99269 -t
7065_8#10 126477 -c
7065_8#10 413711 +T
7065_8#10 586681 -a
7065_8#10 820739 +T
7065_8#10 927102 +T
7065_8#10 942973 +T
7065_8#10 1075448 +G
7065_8#11 99269 -t
7065_8#11 126477 -t
7065_8#11 413711 +T
7065_8#11 470211 +G
7065_8#10 927102 -a
7065_8#10 942973 +T
```

Intermediate results:

```
99269 ( -t -t )
126477 ( -c -t )
413711 ( +T +T )
586681 ( -a )
820739 ( +T )
927102 ( +T -a )
942973 ( +T +T )
1075448 ( +G )
470211 ( +G )
```

Final output:

```
99269 ( -t )
126477 ( -c )
126477 ( -t )
413711 ( +T )
586681 ( -a )
820739 ( +T )
927102 ( +T )
927102 ( -a )
942973 ( +T )
1075448 ( +G )
470211 ( +G )
```

Here is my initial (unsuccessful) code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use 5.010;

my $outputfile = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/positionarray.txt"; 

open FILE1, "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/CC22indelscc.txt";

open (OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile");

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
my @bases = ();
my @words = ();

while (<FILE1>) {
  if (/^\S+\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)/) {
    push @words, $1;
  }
}

my @unique_words = uniq @words;

print OUTPUTFILE "@unique_words\n";

close FILE1;
close OUTPUTFILE;
```

This currently gives me a list of the unique positions on one line separated by spaces, and I can't work out how to print one per line.

Comment: What is it you feel that `say OUTPUTFILE Dumper \@unique_words "@bases";` is doing? That is a syntax error for me.

Comment: `my @words = (); my @uniq_words = uniq @words;` is not ever going to produce anything but an empty list. You create a (new) array, which is empty, and then try to get unique values from it.

Comment: That line ideally would output the unique position before listing the associated indels with it. The original code i was using worked with a simple list of words for 'my @words', however i have struggled to adapt it for my problem using a file.

Comment: Any questions on my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this program does as you ask, but your question isn't clear. It builds a hash of hashes, which removes the need for a separate `uniq` call.

I'm not clear what *numerical positions* or *indels* are, especially as neither term appears in your Perl code, but I have made my best guess.

What I can't tell is whether the *order* of position/indel pairs matters where there are multiple indels at one position. This code prints them in the order they appear in the hash, which is effectively random. If you need them in a different order, such as alphabetical, or the same as they appeared in the file, then you must say so.

I trust you're happy to alter this solution so that it reads and writes to external files, instead of using `DATA` and `STDOUT`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  my ($base, $word) = (split)[1,2];
  ++$data{$base}{$word}
}

for my $base (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data) {
  for my $word (keys %{ $data{$base} }) {
    print "$base ( $word )\n";
  }
}

__DATA__
7065_8#10 99269 -t
7065_8#10 126477 -c
7065_8#10 413711 +T
7065_8#10 586681 -a
7065_8#10 820739 +T
7065_8#10 927102 +T
7065_8#10 942973 +T
7065_8#10 1075448 +G
7065_8#11 99269 -t
7065_8#11 126477 -t
7065_8#11 413711 +T
7065_8#11 470211 +G
7065_8#10 927102 -a
7065_8#10 942973 +T
```

**output**

```
99269 ( -t )
126477 ( -t )
126477 ( -c )
413711 ( +T )
470211 ( +G )
586681 ( -a )
820739 ( +T )
927102 ( +T )
927102 ( -a )
942973 ( +T )
1075448 ( +G )
```

Comment: That gives the perfect output using my file, thank you! I only used that wording as i found my question was too confusing referring to columns of the original file, the indel is just the +t/-t and the numerical position is the numbers in column 2, 99269 etc. The order also doesn't matter at all, all that is important is that each indel/position is in the format you provided in the output file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @EdTickle: You're welcome. In future, if you want to use a technical word or phrase to refer to things concisely, you should *define* the phrase first and then go ahead and use it. For instance *"I need to list the unique numerical positions (second column) and then enumerate the unique indels (third column) after each position"* would have made a world of difference.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll make a list of the errors instead of posting them as comments, as they are starting to mount up.

- `\@unique_words "@bases";` is a syntax error. You need to put a comma between them.
- `my @words = (); my @uniq_words = uniq @words;` cannot produce anything but an empty list. When you use `my` you create a new variable in that scope (block).
- Inside your loop you use `my @words = qw($1);`. This is wrong because:

  1. You create a new variable each loop iteration,
  2. you overwrite that array each time by using `=` instead of push,
  3. `qw($1)` does not interpolate variables, so it just returns a literal `$1`. You don't need `qw()` at all there, and should just push the value like the other line.

Here's what you do:

- Instead of using a regex to match, just split the line, e.g. `my ($junk, $num, $indel) = split`.
- Instead of explicitly opening files for input and output, just use shell redirection and the diamond operator `<>`, e.g. `while (<>)` and `perl script.pl input.txt > output.txt`.
- Store the relevant results of the split in a hash, e.g. `$data{$num}{$indel}++`. If you need to preserve order, store the unique numbers in an array.
- After the loop, go through the stored unique numbers and print the associated keys from the hash using something like `print "$num ( " . join(" ", keys %{$data{$num}}) . ")\n";`

**Edit:**

After reading comments, it is clear that order does not matter, and "indels" should be on separate lines. This allows us to simply print the values as they appear in the file (preserving the original order), and withholding the duplicates from being printed at the same time.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
while (<>) {
    my ($junk, $num, $indel) = split;
    unless (exists $data{$num}{$indel}) {
        print "$num ( $indel )\n";
    }
    $data{$num}{$indel}++;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
perl program.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

In fact, as a purely academic exercise, this can be reduced even further. By (ab)using the fact that postfix incrementation `++` returns a false value the first time it is used on an uninitialized value, we can combine the check and incrementation:

```
my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($junk, $num, $indel) = split;
    unless ($data{$num}{$indel}++) {   # both check and incrementation
        print "$num ( $indel )\n";
    }
}
```

Note that this is just for fun, and not recommended for production code because it is rather obscure.

Comment: Thank you, I've made your changes and it now prints the unique positions in one line, i've edited my original post to include this code. I am unsure how to go about your recommendations though.

Comment: Have a look at Borodin's answer, it is basically the same. Though he did not add the printing of indels on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for your help, between the two of you the code works perfectly.

Comment: If order does not matter, and you want one indel per line, the program can be simplified even more. Then you just need to split, check if the hash key for number and indel exists and if not print it, and then store it. I'll paste in what I made just now.

Answer (score 0):

use a hash which gives you uniqueness be default like this:

```
my %indel_lookup = ();
while (<FILE1>) {
     if (/^\S+\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)/) {
         $indel_lookup{$1}{$2} = undef;
     }
}
```

to print it out use two foreach loops

```
foreach my $position (keys %indel_lookup) {
   foreach my $indel (keys %{$indel_lookup{$position}}) {
        print "$position ( $indel )\n";
   }
}
```

Apart from typos (as it's untested) it should work.

Comment: That will print one number for each indel.

Comment: @TLP: I think that's what is required. The OP's example of multiple indels per number was just an intermediate form: *Initial results* as opposed to *Final output*.

Comment: when I look at what the poster defined as "final" isn't that what was requested?

Comment: @MarcElser: Why on earth are you posting untested code?

Comment: @Borodin Oh, perhaps it is. I was confused by the terminology.

Comment: @TLP: Yes, I think we all were.

Comment: @Borodin. Cause I'm quite sure it is right and because it's just code snippets not a full blown program.

Comment: @MarcElser: You clearly haven't been *"quite sure"* that a piece of code is right enough times yet.

Comment: sorry for not beeing perfect. I just tried to help quickly. Also wanted to get some reputation to vote for good solutions in Stack exchange. Although I'm programming perl for nearly 15 years now, it seems people here just want top notch programmers. I though experience of 15 years allows me to post some untested code....  but hey. maybe it's better if I stop contributing if this is the attitude here.

Answer (score -1):

I removed `use strict` for global variables.  If you want `use strict`, just add `my` in front of the global vars.  Here's the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use 5.010;

my $outputfile = "out.txt";

open FILE1, "in.txt";

open (OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile");

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

%words = ();
while (<FILE1>) {
    if (/^\S+\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)/) {
       $words{$1} .= " ".$2;
    }
}
close FILE1;

for $key (keys(%words)) {
     open FF, ">tmp.txt";
     @uniq_words = uniq split (/\s+/,$words{$key});   
    for $w (@uniq_words) {
        if ($w !~ /^\s*$/) {
            print OUTPUTFILE "$key ( $w )\n";
        }
    }
}

close OUTPUTFILE;
```

Comment: Commenting out `use strict` is in my opinion an offence worthy of a downvote. I won't do it, but others might.

Comment: Well, Perl works on serious long projects as well as quick-and-dirty projects.  I believe that it depends whether to us or not to use `use strict`. In addition, I did mentioned how to uncomment `use strict`.  Down-votes? Are you kidding?  Please note that  `use strict` is NOT the default behavior (Otherwise, we should have a command like `use casual` than `use strict`).  Do you understand why the perl author make 'causal' as default rather than 'strict'?

Comment: Besides, this is a place for exchanging thoughts, codes, etc.. not a place to ask questions and get PERFECT codes.   I was supposed to quickly answer the question TO THE POINT, not perfecting the codes.  By not using `use strict`, I can type less, the codes can be shorter.  It saves me some time, and also save all other's time because they can read a shorter piece of codes.

Comment: Stop being melodramatic. All you need to do to use `strict` is to add `my` in front of your variables the first time you use them. Learn to use `strict` and you will become a much better Perl coder. If you put `strict` back and make your script strict compliant, I will give you an upvote to balance your downvote.

Comment: And while you are at it, you might remove the large commented portion of your code.

Comment: I don't have to learn how to use strict.  I already know how to use it, AND WHEN TO USE IT.  Requesting to remove large comment is accepted. As for strict,.. I think it really depends...

Comment: No, it doesn't, really. There is no tradeoff to using it, you just have to learn to write proper code. Just like using warnings. When you have rid yourself of bad habits, you can no longer imagine writing code without `use strict; use warnings;`, because it is so silly and so filled with subtle traps.